# Sudden Drop in Performance on an iPad AIR application with renderMode=GPU

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ipad, ios4, air

We have an AIR application running on an Apple iPad, that occasionally experiences sudden drop in its performance. The frame rate drops from 60fps to 2fps and it never recovers from that.

Some of our observations are:

- this is only reproducible on iOS 4, but never on iOS 5 - we've
  checked that on two identical iPads (generation 1)
- the performance drops occasionally, but always happens when we switch
  between apps - from our app to another and back
- very rarely, the performance drop also happens on first start of the
  app
- this performance issue does not happen in `renderMode=CPU`, but this
  mode doesn't work for us, because the rendering is ugly, especially
  on rotated bitmaps

Has anyone else experienced similar issues? Any ideas how to workaround it?

Comment: Have you toyed with `cacheAsBitmap` at all? Also, for rotated and/or scaled images on IOS you'll want to use `cacheAsBitmapMatrix`. There's plenty of info online about those two so I'll let you and Google sort it out.

Comment: Yes we use both of these. One reason to use `renderMode=GPU` is exactly the support for `cacheAsBitmapMatrix`. Keep in mind though that `cacheAsBitmapMatrix` works only with the GPU-mode, not CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a AIR runtime bug with the GPU rendering since it happens only on iOS 4 and not iOS 5. However, it is possible that your iOS 4 device has too little on-board GPU memory for keeping all the cached transformations. Once your cache is full, a huge performance drop will be seen (perhaps the same drop your seeing). You should use object pooling as much as possible to keep the cached transformations minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Basically, we have the came to the same conclusions. Right now what we do is to watch the frame rate and when we detect a performance problem, we start switching off `cacheAsBitmap` to `false`. We also remove the caching of the transformation matrices and try to keep the cached objects to a minimum  - only moving/animated objects essential to the UI are cached. Nevertheless, I agree with you that this seems like an AIR bug.